# Ending a while loop without a sentinel

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have an array that can store up to 500 values. when I input 500 values, everything works as it should.. However, I would like to input as many values as I want, 500 or less, and still get an output. for example getting the average for any amount of numbers , 500 or less.

heres my while loop I have now that will not terminate until 500 numbers is reached:

```
public class StatsPackage{

static InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (isr);
String [] inputs = new String [500];
static int inputs2[] = new int [500];
double [] scores = new double [500];
int count;
static int lowest, temp, i = 0;
static double sum, mean, median, sumOfSquares, variance, stdDev;
static boolean even = (inputs2.length & 1) == 0;
static boolean odd  = (inputs2.length % 1) != 0;


static double calcMean (int inputs2[],int count) throws IOException{

    while(i < inputs2.length){
        String inputs = br.readLine();   
        String [] Values = inputs.split ("\\s+");
        inputs2 [i] = Integer.parseInt(Values[0]);                  
        i++; }//end of while loop
    for (i = 0; i < inputs2.length; i++){
        sum = sum + inputs2[i];
    }   
    mean = (sum/count);
    return mean;            
}
```

inputs is my number input string, values is a string array, and i parse the strings from "values" into my integer array, 'inputs2'

Any thoughts or help on how to terminate the loop early?

**Sample Input-**

```
49 66 73 56 3 39 33 77 54 29
```

**Sample Output-**

```
Mean: 47.90
Median: 51.50
Variance: 458.29
Standard Deviation: 21.41
```

Comment: Please post a sample input and the desired output

Comment: input:

49
66
73
56
3
39
33
77
54
29


Output: 
Mean: 47.90
Median: 51.50
Variance: 458.29
Standard Deviation: 21.41

Comment: Show your whole code. The problem most likely has to do with how you are initializing `inputs2`.

Comment: BUT, I would like to be able to get a similar output with anywhere from 0 to 500 inputs. so that input list can be 300 and I'd still get the output. I dont know how to end asking for inputs unless I use a sentinel and for this project I cannot use a sentinel.

Comment: The "% 1" when defining 'odd' above should be "& 1". You're not actually using that anywhere, but if you do use it in the future it will bite you if you don't correct it.

Comment: You should make it clear whether you want the user to enter all values on one line, or enter each value on a separate line, or a mixture of both.

Comment: I do use it later to calculate the median. i use the modulus to determine if the number of inputs is even or odd

Comment: enter a new value in each line

Comment: If you use the modulus, you'll need to do % 2. For any value N, N % M will be a value between 0 and M-1. So taking a value modulus 1 is pointless, as the expression will always yield 0.

Answer (score 3):

You need end-users to tell you when they are done entering their numbers. This could be done in a number of ways. End-users could

- Enter an agreed-upon number (say, `-1`),
- Enter an empty string, or
- Close the input stream by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on UNIX or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows

In all cases you would need to store the count of how many elements you have stored in your `inputs2` array, and use that index to run loops examining the active portion of the array. This is sub-optimal for two reasons:

- You may allocate more memory than you actually need, and
- Your users may want to enter more data than you have provisioned.

To fix both these problems, use `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of an array.

Here is an example implementation that exits when the user enters an empty line:

```
List<Integer> inputs2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(true) {
    String inputs = br.readLine();   
    String [] values = inputs.split ("\\s+");
    if (values.length() == 0)
        break; // Users entered an empty line, so we exit
    for (int i = 0 ; i != values.length() ; i++) {
        inputs2.add(Integer.parseInt(Values[i]));
    }
} //end of while loop
```

Comment: I agree with you, however this is for an assignment in class and the professor does not allow us to use something "he hasnt taught us" - is there some way I can use "null" to end the loop? I've tried to use something like (br.readLine() != null) at the top of the while loop but that gave me an error

Comment: @LandonWiggs You need `while(true)` at the top of the loop, and `if (values.length() == 0) break;` in the middle to stop the loop. See the example for details. Note that the example lets users enter multiple integers on the same line.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Are you telnetable?

Answer (score 0):

Use a special value as loop terminator, eg, "-1", then use it in you while condition to end your loop. You could also check for this condition in the body of the while block and use the `break` statement.